# Passing php variables inside function - stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying pass a value inside stripe function `function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int`  using variable declared outside function, but its not working. But if I declare variable inside the function `function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int` its working. Its confusing.

**What is working**

```
function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
   // assign session amount to a variable
   $amount = 500;
    return $amount;
}
```

**What is not working and what I want**

```
$amount = 500;
function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
   // assign session amount to a variable
    return $amount;
}
```

I am trying to pass a value to the function from outside, kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `$amount` variable to be defined outside the function as a global variable. Then you should tell the function to "import" it like so:

```
$amount = 500;
function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
   global $amount;
   // assign session amount to a variable
   return $amount;
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend using global variables. Use a parameter if this value is intended to change, or a constant otherwise.